# GET_POST_META lowercase

Tags: wordpress, meta

i have this code for array "nacionalidad"

```
<?php global $wp_query; $postid = $wp_query->post->ID; echo get_post_meta($postid, 'nacionalidad', true); ?>
```

But show first character with uppercase. Its possible write the same code but with all characters in lowercase?

Comment: have you tried strtolower()

Comment: i have answered, please go through the answer

Comment: or else you can use a easy method with css
just assign a class and add style text-transform: lowercase;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `strtolower()` function in php

```
    <?php 
    global $wp_query; 
    $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
    $metavalue = get_post_meta($postid, 'nacionalidad', true);
    echo $metavalue = strtolower($metavalue);
 ?>
```

check http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php for more details

Answer (score 0):

i think you need all the characters in lower case..

if yes the use this code

```
<?php 
global $wp_query; 
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
$metavalue = '<span style="text-transform: lowercase;"> ' .get_post_meta($postid, 'nacionalidad', true) . '</span>';
echo $metavalue;
?>
```

this will make letters i lowercase

If u need all the letter in Uppercase

just replace the uppercase with lowercase